# Get Cell Value Webservice for ArcGIS Raster (LiDAR) without using ArcGIS

Tags: geoserver, raster, open-source-gis, web-service, lidar

I want to expose the getCellValue function on Lidar Data, as a web service. But I don't have access to ArcGIS (server or desktop).

What options do I have to fetch cell value, given lat lon, from a raster in ArcGIS format?

It would be great if someone can point me to some open source code/library that I can use to create a web service.  I am open to any other option except ArcGIS.

I know that Geoserver has a raster rendering feature: can it also find the cell value for a lat-long input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a nice alternative to using the ArcGIS toolbox: 
The GDAL Library provides command line binary which takes ADF coverage file path and lat lon as input and returns the cell value.

Here is the link:

http://www.gdal.org/gdallocationinfo.html

Comment: The `-xml` option will be useful for a web service. If your inputs are Long/Lat then `-wgs84` is convenient too.